# Reordering a Dictionary set upon deleting a UITableViewCell row

Tags: swift, dictionary, uitableview, tableview, delete-row

I decided to use dictionaries to populate multiple tableViews with API calls as opposed to using arrays and async await to reduce load times. I call all of my API's in a background thread asynchronously, giving each dictionary an incremented index from 0 up, and when all the API calls are done I sort the dictionary as such:

```
    let sortedDictionary = dictionary.sorted {
        return $0.key < $1.key
    }
```

Then I populate my tableViews; much faster than running the API calls in sequence. Now I have to somehow reorder the tableViews upon deleting a row like you would to a standard array (I have a scrollView with several tableViews, and another tableView that has a row for each tableView; this second tableView is the one which I am deleting rows). This is my attempt, but something in my logic is off, or I'm missing something:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: 
UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == .delete{

        //delete object from dictionary
        self.dictionary.removeValue(forKey: indexPath.row)

        for i in indexPath.row...dictionary.count-1{
            if i == dictionary.count-1{
                //remove last index in the dictionary at end of loop
                self.dictionary.removeValue(forKey: i)
            } else{
                //increment all dictionary indices past the deleted row down one
                let j = i+i
                let value = dictionary[j]
                guard let value = value else {return}
                self.dictionary.removeValue(forKey: j)
                self.dictionary.updateValue(value, forKey: i)
            }

        }
        
}

}
```

It seems that I'm running into a null here:

```
guard let value = value else {return}
```

Is this not the correct way to store a dictionary value?

```
let value = dictionary[j]
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Dictionaries cannot be sorted I believe and so if you look at `sortedDictionary`, it should be an array. I think instead of using the dictionary, you should use the`sortedDictionary` array as your data source and remove items from that.

Comment: That was my initial instinct but I couldnt access dictionary methods from it. So youre saying sorting the dictionary actually turns it into an array and I can use sortedDictionary.remove(at: indexPath.row)?

Comment: Yes, you could do that with an array. If you look at the `sorted` function https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2298238-sorted - it returns an array back to you. Dictionaries are unordered collections. `sortedDictionary` is an array sorted by the `key`

Comment: From what you do (ie recomputing key when deleting item) it seems that you could work with an array. If you want to work with a dictionary you could also have an array that contains the sorted keys.

Comment: Alternatively, if you still need a sorted dictionary, Apple has a package Swift Collections that you can use: https://github.com/apple/swift-collections It has `OrderedDictionary`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue and formatted it into a templated function so that it can be used on multiple dictionary models. As comments above mentioned, dictionaries can simply be sorted, but this is another way to do it:

```
func deleteRows<T>(indexPath: IndexPath, dictionary: inout Dictionary<Int, T>){
    
    if indexPath.row == dictionary.count-1{
        //if its the last object in the tableView, delete and return
        dictionary.removeValue(forKey: indexPath.row)
        return
    }

    //store last object in dictionary
    let lastIndex = dictionary[dictionary.count-1]
    
    for i in indexPath.row...dictionary.count-1{
         if i == dictionary.count-2{
             //remove last object in the dictionary at end of loop
             dictionary.removeValue(forKey: dictionary.count-1)
             //append last object
             guard let lastIndex = lastIndex else {return}
             dictionary.updateValue(lastIndex, forKey: dictionary.count-1)
         } else if i < dictionary.count-1{
             //increment all dictionary indices past the deleted row down one
                 let value = dictionary[i+i]
                 guard let value = value else {return}
                 dictionary.updateValue(value, forKey: i)
         }

     }
}
```